# How to create a subtotal record in pandas using certain rows data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

My current code is something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]})

df = df.append({'animal': 'Total Land', 'num_specimen_seen': df.loc[df['animal']=='falcon','num_specimen_seen']+df.loc[df['animal']=='dog','num_specimen_seen']+df.loc[df['animal']=='spider','num_specimen_seen']}, ignore_index=True)

df
```

In the above code, I'm creating a new record for animal column called **Total Land** and its num_specimen_seen is being calculated by referencing corresponding land animals count. Is there a better way to achieve my desired result provided below ?

I preferably wouldn't want to create a subset of current dataframe to use .sum functionality as I need to do above operation multiple times

Current Output:

|  | animal | num_specimen_seen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | falcon | 10 |
| 1 | dog | 2 |
| 2 | spider | 1 |
| 3 | fish | 8 |
| 4 | Total Land | 0 NaN 1 NaN 2 NaN Name: num_specimen_see... |

Expected Output:

|  | animal | num_specimen_seen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | falcon | 10 |
| 1 | dog | 2 |
| 2 | spider | 1 |
| 3 | fish | 8 |
| 4 | Total Land | 13 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sum` like below:

```
df = df.append({'animal': 'Total Land', 
                'num_specimen_seen': df['num_specimen_seen'][df['animal'].isin(['falcon', 'dog','spider'])].sum()}, ignore_index=True)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Ya, maybe some SO cache? Sometimes happens.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `sum`:

```
new = df.loc[df['animal'].isin(['falcon', 'dog','spider']), 'num_specimen_seen'].sum()
df = df.append({'animal': 'Total Land', 'num_specimen_seen': new}, ignore_index=True)

print (df)
       animal  num_specimen_seen
0      falcon                 10
1         dog                  2
2      spider                  1
3        fish                  8
4  Total Land                 13
```

For one line solution use (unfortunately hard readable):

```
df = df.append({'animal': 'Total Land', 
                'num_specimen_seen': df.loc[df['animal'].isin(['falcon', 'dog','spider']), 'num_specimen_seen'].sum()}, ignore_index=True)
```